# Dual authentication for document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication

We have a SharePoint 2010 environment setup to use Kerberos which works wonderfully - users within our network are authenticated automatically and are not presented with a login prompt.

For some areas of our sites, we require an additional authentication step to be presented to the user.  This is mostly for document libraries that contain personal, private data that requires a two-stage authentication to access in order to conform with organization policies currently in place.

Is there a method to apply a second level of authentication to a document library, page, or site within a site collection in order to access secure, private data?

Thanks

Comment: Why a second level?  If this is for audit purposes, SharePoint supports auditing who views what directly out of the box

Comment: It is actually not auditing - but a policy we must enforce due to government regulations.  All data of this type must be secured by two-layer authentication (whatever form that takes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to handle this at the IIS level with two-factor authentication.  You could write custom code in SharePoint to try to accomplish this, but trying to write your own security layers is usually a bad idea.

Microsoft offers the Windows Azure Multi-Factor Authentication service that might work for you: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249479.aspx

Comment: There are many third-party options, such as: http://ds3global.com/index.php/en/secure-microsoft-sharepoint-access-with-ds3-two-factor-authentication-2fa-solution, http://www.secureauth.com/web-applications/microsoft-sharepoint/, or http://enterprise.comodo.com/security-solutions/authentication-identity-assurance/two-factor/trial-form.php.

Comment: Also, the new Web Application Proxy, which is part of Windows Server 2012 R2, has support for two-factor authentication: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280942.aspx